# I get 2 semicolons in my figure references

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

I get `;;` in the place where the number of the figure should be. I compiled 2 times but still the same. Elsewhere in my text I got proper reference of the figure I wanted.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
            \usepackage{graphicx}
            \usepackage{caption}
            \usepackage{refstyle}
            .........
                 \begin{figure}[h]
                 \centering
                \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{location}
                \caption{Θέση του γονιδίου της δυστροφίνης}
                \label{fig:location}
                \end{figure}
        \cleardoublepage 
    .....
\end{document}
```

I call the ref by:

```
(Σχήμα \ref{fig:location}) ....
```

[image: this is what I get]

Strange thing is that the below code works fine in the text.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{image1}
\caption{ Απεικόνιση τρόπου κληρονομικότητας υπολειπόμενων φυλοσύνδετων γονιδίων ({\en X-linked disease})}
\label{fig:image1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Could you post a complete MWE? It would be very helpful.

Comment: hope this is what you wanted as MWE.

Comment: Nearly! A MWE always starts with `\documentclass …`, goes to `\begin{document}` and ends with `\end{document}` …

Comment: The code you posted isn't a "MWE", the purpose of the example is to let people run the code to see the problem and debug the issue. If you try to run the code you posted you will get the error `! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.` which is unrelated to your question so the code is not useful as a test document.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

normally on the first pass you would get two ?? so this may just be an encoding issue that you get `;;`
 You need to run latex at least twice for the cross references to resolve.

Also the `\label` needs to be in the same scope as the `\caption`

in

```
\caption{Θέση του γονιδίου της δυστροφίνης}
\end{center}
\label{fig:location}
```

the caption number is lost at the `\end{center}` so you need

```
\caption{Θέση του γονιδίου της δυστροφίνης}
\label{fig:location}
\end{center}
```

or better use `\centering` rather than `\begin{center}..\end{center}` in figures as `center` adds extra vertical space not required here (as `figure` already adds vertical space.